# Rajawali Loading .FBX File

Tags: android, rajawali

I have downloaded latest Rajawali examples. I have tried to load .FBX file downloaded from internet

1. put file in raw dir (download  from here https://free3d.com/3d-model/wolf-rigged-and-game-ready-42808.html)
2. My class is here

   ```
      try {
           LoaderFBX parser = new LoaderFBX(this,
                   R.raw.wolf_fbx);
           parser.parse();
           Object3D o = parser.getParsedObject();
           o.setY(-.5f);
           getCurrentScene().addChild(o);
       } catch (ParsingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   ```

this code throws  java.util.EmptyStackException

```
04-29 19:33:11.657 17786-17906/com.monyetmabuk.rajawali.tutorials W/System.err: org.rajawali3d.loader.ParsingException: java.util.EmptyStackException
04-29 19:33:11.657 17786-17906/com.monyetmabuk.rajawali.tutorials W/System.err:     at org.rajawali3d.loader.fbx.LoaderFBX.parse(LoaderFBX.java:140)
04-29 19:33:11.657 17786-17906/com.monyetmabuk.rajawali.tutorials W/System.err:     at com.monyetmabuk.rajawali.tutorials.examples.loaders.FBXFragment$FBXRenderer.initScene(FBXFragment.java:68)
04-29 19:33:11.657 17786-17906/com.monyetmabuk.rajawali.tutorials W/System.err:     at org.rajawali3d.renderer.Renderer.onRenderSurfaceSizeChanged(Renderer.java:346)
04-29 19:33:11.657 17786-17906/com.monyetmabuk.rajawali.tutorials W/System.err:     at org.rajawali3d.view.TextureView$GLThread.guardedRun(TextureView.java:1266)
04-29 19:33:11.657 17786-17906/com.monyetmabuk.rajawali.tutorials W/System.err:     at org.rajawali3d.view.TextureView$GLThread.run(TextureView.java:997)
04-29 19:33:11.657 17786-17906/com.monyetmabuk.rajawali.tutorials W/System.err: Caused by: java.util.EmptyStackException
04-29 19:33:11.657 17786-17906/com.monyetmabuk.rajawali.tutorials W/System.err:     at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
04-29 19:33:11.657 17786-17906/com.monyetmabuk.rajawali.tutorials W/System.err:     at org.rajawali3d.loader.fbx.LoaderFBX.readLine(LoaderFBX.java:602)
04-29 19:33:11.657 17786-17906/com.monyetmabuk.rajawali.tutorials W/System.err:     at org.rajawali3d.loader.fbx.LoaderFBX.parse(LoaderFBX.java:136)
04-29 19:33:11.657 17786-17906/com.monyetmabuk.rajawali.tutorials W/System.err:     ... 4
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm trying to load a FBX file.